# Time Range Validation in MySQL VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have schedule_tbl in table in my Database for the professor and have starting_time, ending_time and day column. I would like to do is, if I inserted a starting of 7:00:00 to 10:00:00 then all that counters 7:00:00-10:00:00 is invalid.

Example my record

```
starting_time     ending_time     day
7:00:00           10:00:00        Monday
```

Inserting

```
6:00:00           8:00:00         Monday
```

Then it must be invalid. So far this is my code.

```
    ("SELECT * FROM schedule_tbl WHERE "' and starting_time >= '" & _
 Me.dtpStart.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss") & "' and ending_time <= '" & _
 Me.dtpEnd.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss") & "' and day = '" & ComboBox4.Text & "'", conn3)
```

Its working but only in the range between the starting_time and ending_time. If I input **6:00:00 for starting_time** and **9:00:00 for ending_time**, its adding up to the Database which should be **invalid**.

Comment: a) use parameters instead of string concatenation to build queries.  it will make the code more readable (among other things), 2) you are converting the time to text (see a); strings will not compare the same as time values, c) what is the column type in the db?

Comment: I'm not fully understand you request.. can you expand the explaination on your logic ?

Comment: @Plutonix im sorry the datatype is time

Comment: @sagi sorry for my bad logic what I want is all that counters 7:00:00 - 10:00:00 which starting_time and ending_time will be invalid. for exampale i have 7-10AM recorded in my database and when the user inserted 6:00:00 - 8:30:00 it will be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad there just a problem with my if else statement instead of using **OR** I coded **AND** its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The correct logic for determining if two periods overlap is that the first starts before the second ends and the first ends after the second starts.  The logic to get overlaps looks like this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM schedule_tbl s
WHERE s.starting_time < $EndTime and
      s.ending_time > $StartTime;
```

Note:  You might want `>=` and `<=` for your problem rather than strict inequalities.

Comment: @MeykaJograt . . . "not working" is extremely vague and provides not additional information for helping.  The logic in the answer is correct.  Your implementation may not be.